# On browser back Livewire page is design broken

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

I have used Livewire in one of the projects, where I am getting bizarre issues.

On page load, the site works smoothly, however any error occurs then ignition styles are injected in the DOM, and then I click on the browser back button the website page design is broken as ignition styles are injected.

Initial page
[image: Inital page]

This is an error page.
[image: Error page]

After clicking on the back button.
[image: After clicking on the back button]

**Expected output:**

On the browser back button, the page design keeps looking the same as shown on the page load.